# Size function for ruby Fixnum class

Tags: ruby, internals

Why the ruby size function for the number returning output like this?

```
1000000.size              # => 8
99999999999999999999.size # => 9
```

Comment: It would help the Ruby authors tremendously, if you could point out *exactly* which part of the `size` method's documentation you don't understand, so that they can improve it for future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby internally uses two different structures for storing integers - `Fixnum` and `Bignum`. The first one is used for smaller number and maps directly to a long integer on the host architecture. It's faster and constant in size, but limited on how much it can store. The latter is used for storring arbitrarily large numbers and its size depends on how big the number is.

```
1000000.class              # => Fixnum
99999999999999999999.class # => Bignum
```

The conversion is done internally. In fact with ruby 2.4.0, there will be only one class - `Integer`.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the action done by the size function?

Comment: @Vivakkumar it basically says how much memory (in bytes) is used to store the number.

Comment: Is it returning bitwise memory representation?

Comment: @Vivakkumar, no, only how many bytes it requires to be stored.